# SHAREit is not working

Tags: playonlinux, shareit

I have downloaded SHAREit for PC. It is a windows application. And I have playonlinux installed in my ubuntu 14.04. But still it I can't work with SHAREit in my ubuntu. I am able to double click the SHAREit.exe file so that my system monitor shows up it in the list as you can see below.

[image]

Other than that, I don't see anything on my desktop. The application isn't opening for use. Help me to use it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do check the related wine page on `winehq`. You can find more info there than anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

right click on that exe file and select open with and then select play on linux and click ok...
                                 -lucifer